# MacBook Pro SSD issue

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, macos, time-machine, ssd

I brought new SSD 240 GB and I using this SSD by Caddy. The SSD is showing in Finder. I can format it. The SMART Status is verified. But when I try to install any OS or restore my OS, it goes into infinity. I tried normal install and Time Machine restore.

[image]

Something is wrong, I can't install any OS on the new SSD. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have you partitioned it to be a GUID HFS+ Journaled non-case sensitive volume?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the settings for the SSD underneath the Kingston?